# Decryption is not happening in soap ui

Tags: encryption, soap, soapui, jks, wsse

Encryption is happening successfully in soap ui it is reaching server and server is replying with proper response without any issue. However while upon receiving in soap the encrypted response is not getting decrypted and in error log I'm getting the following error.

> ERROR:org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security
>   error (No certificates were found for decryption (KeyId))
>   org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (No
>   certificates were found for decryption (KeyId))
>          at org.apache.ws.security.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.getCertificatesFromEncryptedKey(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:313)

In incoming configuration , I configured the jks file which consists my keypair and server public key.
( the same jks file is working fine when using in java client code , So I assume this is a problem in soap ui configuration. )

Any help would be appreciated